# Is $mSn \iff 2m+n$ is even an equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We have relation $S$ in natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, defined with $mSn \iff 2m + n$ which is an even number. Is S an equivalence relation?

Comment: Take $ m $ odd. Then $2m+m=3m $ is odd, so $ m\not S m $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2\cdot 1+1$ is not an even number, so $1\not S 1$ and the reflexive axiom is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

To show that something is an equivalence relation you have to show that it is:

- Reflexive
- Symmetric
- Transitive

If any of these fail, you don't have an equivalence relation.

$S$ is such that $m$ is related to $n$ if (and only if) $2m+n$ is an even number.
Reflexivity means that every element has to be related to itself. Thus $1$ has to be related to $1$, $2$ related to $2$ and so on. This fails for $1$ (and other elements of $\mathbb{N}$ as well), can you see why?